# How to pass data through service if change detection method exist in one of the component?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-changedetection

I need to update the color of particular box in one component by getting input from second component. For this I am using service to pass data but due to change detection i can't update color. I need solution to update color with change detection method.

Stack blitz link: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/best-example-of-passing-data-through-an-object-us-pgectp?file=app%2Fone%2Fone.component.html,app%2Fone%2Fone.component.ts,app%2Fone%2Fone.component.css,app%2Ftwo%2Ftwo.component.html,app%2Ftwo%2Ftwo.component.ts,app%2Fdata.service.ts,app%2Fchange-color.directive.ts,app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` this tells angular to only fire changeDetection cycle when one of the following is done

`subscription via async pipe`,
`input reference changes`,
`manual trigger via detectChanges()`

You have none of these on component `one`

Then comes second point: (recommendation)
When you are setting up some kind of state management, you have to emit subject both as observable and as plain value.

You need observable because of first point, without it you will not be able to refresh template values if you don't run manual detectChanges.

You need plain value because sometimes u dont to need render received value in template, but just perform some kind of logic on it and that's it. In your case, this would be called `buttonStateSnapshot`

And don't make state variables public, this is a risk. Somehow they can get modified. Modify state with functions, without direct access.

Not sure how you set up you logic with boxes, but I've retouched service and template a bit and now the first box does change color

https://stackblitz.com/edit/best-example-of-passing-data-through-an-object-us-qfcbpo?file=app%2Fone%2Fone.component.html,app%2Fone%2Fone.component.ts,app%2Fone%2Fone.component.css,app%2Ftwo%2Ftwo.component.html,app%2Ftwo%2Ftwo.component.ts,app%2Fchange-color.directive.ts,app%2Fdata.service.ts

Comment: Thank you for solution. It works fine. I'm using async pipe for value binding thats why using change detection. I gave only sample example in stackblitz. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

On component One, that has `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, when subscribe to value changes, you need to run `detectChanges` from service `ChangeDetectorRef`.